# Do external GPUs combine forces with an existing GPU or totally replace it?

Tags: gpu

```
Dell Latitude 5580 (laptop)
Thunderbolt in some version (evident from socket, BIOS and successful installation of drivers) 
Nvidia Gforce 940MX
Windows 10 Home
```

The internal GPU 940MX is a bit weak for me to run [Diablo 2: Resurrected](https://diablo2.blizzard.com/en-us/) and I think to buy an external GPU.

Do external GPUs combine forces with an existing GPU or totally replace it?

Will the external GPU combine forces with the 940MX or will totally replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't replace and they don't combine either.

As far as I know an external Thunderbolt or USB connected GPU (that would be the only options for this laptop) will exist in parallel to the onboard GPU.
They can't work together/use each others resources.

Comment: So, when I play the game, how could I know / choose which GPU to use?... If there is no replacement?

Comment: @asmaraismeralda - If the application supports it, an option to choose which GPU to use, is typically offered.  Otherwise it would likely be up to the application.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, gosh, I should check if Diablo 2: Ressurected supports it.

Comment: @Ramhound I assume that what I can do is somehow disable the internal GPU and use the external one, at least before I play games.

Comment: @asmaraismeralda - I just know that even with an internal dGPU you would have the option to use the iGPU or dGPU depending on the application

Comment: @asmaraismeralda You don't need an external GPU for Diablo2 Resurrected. That would be utter overkill. I play that game too and it is very lightweight on the CPU. In fact: I run it on an older NUC with Intel HD GPU (which is less capable than the Geforce 940MX) which works just fine. I can even Remote Desktop to that PC from my iMac and play the game over Remote Desktop without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tonny said, they will work parallel but not combine.

Windows will decide when to use one or the other, and you can change that in settings for specific programs(https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/), and you can see which one is being used for each program in Activity Monitor>"GPU Engine".

You may need third party programs to switch GPUs more effectively(i.e. Razer's GPU Switcher, etc.).

Alternatively, if you have two monitors, you can plug one monitor into the display out port of one GPU and the other into the display output of the other GPU, if applicable.  Again, check settings to make sure each screen is running the right GPU.

You may need to be careful when combining an AMD GPU and a Nvidia GPU, but I think it's totally doable if you do some research (only for eGPU and dGPU/iGPU, not for two dGPUs).